# django-background-tasks integration

Tags: django, import, background-task

I have a simple django app that provides a login page and an authenticated dashboard. I have created a data model, and the dashboard view displays this data, taken from the django database.

I have created a class that processes the data in this model. The class is not involved in the app views directly, it only modifies db content. A repeating function registered with django-background-tasks is used to call various class functions to process db data.

Currently I define the class and the django-background-task function in a single file in the django app. I instantiate the class in this file too.

In order to schedule the repeating django-background-task function I need to call it once from somewhere within the django project. Where in the django file structure would be best to do this?

In apps.py? Is the db ready at this point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a suggested answer to this question in the following post:

https://medium.com/@robinttt333/running-background-tasks-in-django-f4c1d3f6f06e

The author suggests placing the function to be called repeatedly in a file called tasks.py - I missed this point in the readme docs of the package. Also the author suggests adding the call that triggers the initial scheduling of the repeated task in urls.py.

I tried this solution and it worked fine, although using urls.py doesn't seem the most inuitive or logical location. If anyone has any other suggestions I would be interested to hear them.

Ta.